# How to redirect custom sub domains to my wildcard subdomain?

Tags: nginx

Users can create subdomains with my root domain using my angular project. So, we are using wildcard subdomain to create subdomains. We are nginx. Now, our requirement is, if user wants a custom sub domain, then he should able to point his custom sub domain with our wildcard subdomain. How we can achieve this?

Eg: User has subdomain user.abc.com and we are providing *.xyz.com.
User created a sub domain hello.xyz.com, now he wants to redirect his user.abc.com to hello.xyz.com.  How can we achieve this scenario with nginx.

Answer (score 0):

In your nginx conf file if you mention `server_name *.domain.com;` all of your subdomains should be pointed to the same angular project.

However, note that you will also need to create a name server for the subdomain created by the customer pointing to server IP.

For e.g., if you're using AWS DNS service Route 53 then whenever customer creates the new subdomain then you will have to create the same under route 53 and point it to application server IP

Comment: Thankyou Punith for your quick reply.  In nginx, we already added server_name and we are able to redirect all wild card subdomains to angular project. The problem is coming only when end user wants to configure his own sub domain with our wild card domain. We tried with CNAME. But no use. Also we dont want to create each sub domain under Route 53. Is there any other alternative like CNAME??

Comment: Then you can also try creating an A record with *.domain.com pointing to your server IP. So that whichever subdomain customer uses request will be coming to your server 

e.g., `*.domain.com  A  server IP`

Comment: but, how to redirect to custom(user own) subdomain to our server IP

Comment: Since *.domain.com is pointed to server IP , then any custom domain request will come to server

Comment: yes, exactly what you are saying is correct. That custom domain request is coming to our IP only. but the problem is after request hits to our ip, our nginx throwing 404 error and its redirecting to default 404 page.